# Area below and above a curve compensate

Tags: calculus

Consider the graph below:

[image]

Don't worry about the units in the axes, it might look like a physics question, but my question is purely mathematical. Basically, the work done is the area under this force/displacement graph. For $x_0 = 10$, this work done is $100J$, which in our case also equals the kinetic energy, as there is no friction. Sorry if this sounds to physics-y, but I want to know at which displacement the kinetic energy equals 0.

So the physics behind it I've done; At $x=-10$, the KE reaches a maximum of $150J$. So I figured out that the area between the x-axis and the positive part of the line must equal the area between $x=10$ and $x=-10$, which as I've said is 150.

So now my question: How can I find at which value of $x$ the area below the line equals 150? In other words:

$$\displaystyle \int_{-q}^{-10} f(x) = 150 $$

Where $-q$ is the value we want. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the equation of $f(x)$ and then integrate it from $-q$ to $-10$. For the equation of $f$ you need its slope. The slope of $f$ is $-1$. So its equation is $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$ where $m$ is the slope. Take $(x_0,y_0)=(0,-10)$, so 
$$y-0=-1(x-(-10))=-x-10$$
$$\int_{-q}^{-10}(-x-10)\ dx=150$$